# Feature matching and detection between two images

Tags: python, image, image-processing

Hi I am new to feature detection, I am trying to find matches to an image in other image, How can this is be performed in a simple​ way and is there a way to determine the percentage match ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this starter code to get familiar with feature matching and read up more on feature detection [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d27/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html)

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im1 = cv2.imread('Feature1.png')
im2 = cv2.imread('Image.png')
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# initialize the AKAZE descriptor, then detect keypoints and extract
# local invariant descriptors from the image
detector = cv2.AKAZE_create()
(kps1, descs1) = detector.detectAndCompute(gray1, None)
(kps2, descs2) = detector.detectAndCompute(gray2, None)

# Match the features
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)
matches = bf.knnMatch(descs1,descs2, k=2)
```